# Lambda with for_each to delete elements from vector

Tags: c++, vector, lambda

I want to pass a lambda function to **for_each** that captures a vector and delete all the elements that less than 10, it works partially but still showing elements that less than 10.

can anyone know what's wrong with it? the below code shows (10  8   5   6   4   77  15)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
int main(){

    std::vector<int>vec{10,3,8,2,5,9,6,7,4,1,77,15};
    std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[&vec](int x){if(x<10) vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),x),vec.end());});
    for(auto&i:vec)
    std::cout<<i<<'\t';
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `remove_if`/`erase`?

Comment: The `erase` in the lambda invalidates the iterators of the `for_each` ... Why not use `remove_if`?

Comment: Modifying a vector while looping over it via iterators is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @StephenNewell OP is asking why a piece of code isn't working. A duplicate target that shows how to write a piece of code that sidesteps the OP's problem isn't really a duplicate.

Comment: I added a duplicate that I believe more directly answers the question "What's wrong with it?"

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah, that's much closer, thanks.

Comment: @DrewDormann it is clear for me now thanks, for_each was not meant for modifications

Comment: @Zerocool_m12 If the compiler supports C++ 20 then just write  std::erase_if( vec, []( const auto &item ) { return item < 10; } );

Comment: @aschepler "*Modifying a vector while looping over it via iterators is a recipe for disaster*" - only if you don't manage the iterators correctly (as is the case here). For instance, this will work fine: `auto it = vec.begin(); while (it != vec.end()) { if (*it < 10){ it = vec.erase(it); } else { ++it; } }`. But I agree that using `remove_if()`+`erase()` or `erase_if()` would be better.